# Developing an SNMP agent for linux

Tags: linux, snmp, network-monitoring, agent

I'm developing a snmp agent for linux and I wonder if there is a directory or file proper protocol statistics snmp OIDs to develop snmpInPkts, snmpOutPkts, snmpInBadVersions, snmpInBadCommunityNames.

I ask because I found in the /proc/net/snmp all statistics for protocols like IP, ICMP, TCP and UDP.

Thank you.

Comment: You're looking for MIBs, I think... and there are A LOT of them.

Comment: You should search for RFC MIBs of the topic.

Comment: I know which are the object identifiers, I want to know is how to get their values ​​from the operating system when provided.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux?

You might be able to find some in /usr/share/snmp/ or /usr/local/share/snmp.

You will probably need to install the snmp packages though.
On Ubuntu, apt-get install snmp.
On RPM based Os, I think you need to install net-snmp-utils.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. The idea is not install anything and I can get the values. I'll have to parse the packets and get the statistics.